# Asp.Net button causing Error 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net

I have a program that reads book info from a database and creates a shopping cart program. It runs fine locally but whenever I test it on my site, I get an Error 500 - Internal Server Error. I've found out that if I comment out the asp:button in the code below, the program works but the button is necessary. The Button3_Click function exists in the code behind. Any ideas?

`<div id="book3" class="books" style="width: 170px; height: 351px; float:left;">&nbsp;
    <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="196px" Width="169px" ImageUrl="url/ofMiceandMen.jpg" />
    <br />
    <div style="height: 135px">
    <asp:Label ID="title" runat="server" Text="Of Mice and Men"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="author" runat="server" Text="John Steinbeck"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="review" runat="server" Text="4.5/5 Stars"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="price" runat="server" Text="$7.00"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button3_Click" Text="View Book" /> 
    //This Button
    </div>
</div>`

This is what the server tells me when I specify for detailed debug info.

Detailed Error Information:

Module:        ManagedPipelineHandler

Notification:      MapRequestHandler

Handler:       PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0

Error Code     0x00000000

Comment: And you're positive that your program is connecting properly, with the proper connection string in your web.config?

Comment: Have you looked on the server's event viewer to see what the error message is?

Comment: I've taken away the connection part and just hard coded in the values for testing and the error still persists.

Comment: Is the error coming when the page is loading or on post back? There is a major difference here that could be quite useful for debugging.

Comment: The error occurs when the page is loading.

Comment: You have more going on than just your code. There is a configuration issue with your website, or IIS is not setup the same way on your server as it is on your local dev machine. I would concentrate on the server at this point instead of your code.

Comment: ManagedPipeLineHandler is an aspect of the application pool. Have you verified that your application pool is configured correctly for your site? Is it running under the correct user account? Is it targeting the correct version of the .NET Framework? Are 32-bit applications enabled if they need to be?

Comment: I've uploaded previous asp.net files that were targeting the 4.5 .NET framework that worked fine. The only difference with this one is I've wrapped it in a project since I have custom c# classes I want included. Is there a difference between uploading pure asp.net classes versus uploading classes part of a project that would cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and I researched but found a lot of answers that did not fix it. Here are my solution steps

1. If the page is a html page, add a form tag with an id and runat inside the <body> tags

```html
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
<!--Add your button -->
          </div>
       </form>
```

and possibly add a <div></div> inside the <form> tags